# How do I keep the hash (#) in a URL while using utm query strings in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, url

I've got a website that uses hash `#` to identify URLs. So URLs might look like:

`www.mywebsite.com/somepage.aspx#productname`

Obviously, "product name" is important here, and I need it to show up in Google Analytics, and by default, it does - the above URL shows up in GA as: `somepage.aspx#productname`

However, the tricky bit comes when I also need to add Google Analytics campaign parameters. They of course need to be added before the hash, so the above URL might need to look like this:

`www.mywebsite.com/somepage.aspx?utm_source=source&utm_medium=medium#productname`

However, if I do this, the page will just show up in Google Analytics as "somepage.aspx". Is there a way to make it so that even when using campaign parameters, I can still keep the part of the URL after the hash in the Google Analytics page name?

Comment: Have you tried doing it like this:
www.mywebsite.com/somepage.aspx#productname?utm_source=source&utm_medium=medium

Comment: Query strings won't work if they're after the hash. But, MrSponge's answer below seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not use `#` as campaign parameter instead?

See [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiCampaignTracking#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setAllowAnchor) from Google Analythics:

> _setAllowAnchor(bool) 
>  This method sets the # sign as the query string delimiter in campaign tracking. This option is set to false by
>   default.
>
> Conventional campaign tracking URLs use the question mark (?) to
>   indicate the beginning of key/value pairs that make up the query. If
>   you set this option to true, your campaign tracking URLs can use a
>   pound (#) sign instead of the question mark (?) to indicate the
>   beginning of the query string.

Comment: If I enable _setAllowAnchor, will "legacy" URLs which still use the question mark for Google Analytics campaign parameters still work as normal?

Comment: @Ascendant: Yes, this should still be the case.